# How to store a complex model in redis using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I would like to know how can I store a object of the next model in Redis Cache

```
class Invoice
end

class Issuer
end

class Recipient
end
```

An invoice has one issuer and recipient

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, what I neded was to serialize my models, I follow the next tutorial

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json